# Show that every ideal of the ring $\mathbb Z$ is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $\mathbb Z$ be the ring of integers. The question asks to show  that every ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is principal. I beg someone to help me because it is a new concept to me.

Comment: (I assume you mean $\mathbb{Z}$ the ring of integers, not only "a ring"...) An ideal is, in particular, a subgroup. Do you know what the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are?

Comment: "Let Z be a ring" is wrong. The question is about the _particular_ ring whose proper name is $\mathbb Z$, namely the ring of ordinary integers under ordinary addition and multiplication.

Comment: Well one thing is if you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an euclidean domain then it is automatically a PID.

Comment: There was a question on showing that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic which might help (although largely focused on the finite case): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6998

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Goal: show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) (or PID).

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb Z$.
If $I={0}$ then $0$ generates $I$. And we are done.

Suppose $I\neq {0}$, and let $a$ be the smallest positive element in $I$.

Claim: $a$ generates $I$ i.e $(a)=I$.

To prove my claim, clearly $(a)\subset I$
Since $(a)$= {$ar :r \in \mathbb Z$}, $ar\in I$

Let $b \in I$ if $b=0$ then $b=a0 \in (a)$.

If $b\neq 0$, we may assume $b>0$, and by the euclidean algorithm we have

$$b=aq+r.$$
Moreover, $0\le r<a$, and of course $q,r \in \mathbb Z$.

Now, $r=b-aq \in I$ since $b,a \in I$. this implies $r=0$ since $r<a$ and $a$ is the smallest element in $I$.

So, $b=aq \in I$. Thus, $(a)=I$, meaning that $a$ generates $I$.

Comment: "we may assume $b>0$": There is no need to assume $b>0$, or even to treat $b=0$ as a separate case.

Comment: Remark that in $\mathbb Z$ it is a bit simpler to use (repeated) *subtraction*, versus *division* (with remainder) - see my answer. This corresponds to the subtractive (vs. divisive) form of the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @Hassan The proof has a (minor) error in that it implicitly assumes $a$ is positive. Instead, it should say:  $I\ne 0 $ implies $I$ has a *positive* element. Let $a$ be the least *positive* element in $I$.

Comment: @Jack Maney: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @HassanMuhammad "let $a$ be the smallest element in $I$" without a further explanation it is not clear that in $I$, a subset of $\mathbb Z$, a smallest element exists.

Comment: I am new to Ring theory, but is it OK to assume $\mathbb Z$ is an Euclidean Domain in which we can apply Euclidean Algorithm?

Answer (score 8):

$\textbf{Hint-}$Every ideal is an additive subgroup and every subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $I=(0)$, it’s certainly principal, so assume that it contains a non-zero element. Since $I$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, if it contains a non-zero element, it must contain a positive element. Let $m$ be the smallest positive member of $I$. Show that $I=(m)$, the set of multiples of $m$.

HINT: Use the division algorithm and a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT** $\ $ In $\rm\:\mathbb Z\:,\:$ descent via the Division (Euclidean) algorithm has especially simple form, viz.

**LEMMA** $\ \ $ If a nonempty set of positive integers $\rm\: M\:$ satisfies $\rm\ n > m\ \in\ M \ \Rightarrow\ \: n-m\ \in\ M$ 
 then every element of $\rm\:M\:$ is a multiple of the least element $\rm\:m_{\:1} \in M\:.$

**Proof** $\ \: $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\:n\in M\:,$ contra  $\rm\:n-m_{\:1} \in M\:$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\:m_{\:1}.$

**REMARK** $\ $ Note that the lemma depends only on the fact that $\rm M$ is discrete and closed under subtraction, so it applies much more generally, e.g. to $\:\mathbb Z$-modules $\subset \mathbb Q\:.\ $ The study of these "fractional ideals" essentially go back to Euclid, who studied the application of the Euclidean algorithm to "line segments" to determine their "greatest common measure". This leads quite naturally to the study of the continued fraction expansion of a real number.

Answer (score 4):

Let $I \subset \mathbb{Z}$ be an ideal; we want to show that $I$ is generated by only one 
  element of $I$, that is, it is a principal. If $I=0$, then $I= \langle 0 \rangle$. 
  Let us assume then that $I \ne 0$, so there is a smallest positive number on $I$. We call 
  this number $n$ and claim that $I = \langle n \rangle $.  Let us pick $m \in I$ and divide 
  it by $n$ with remainder. The division theorem (a proof of Euclid's the division theorem 
  is found in the link below:
 http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s5_1.pdf
  states that there should be a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$ such that $m = q n + r$,
  with $0 \le r < n$.  We proof that $r=0$. We have that $r=m - q n \in I$, and since
  we assumed that $n$ is the smallest positive in $I$, then $r=0$. This means
  that every number on $I$ is of the form $q n$, and the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is PID.

We need to be careful here. Assume that we have the following ideal:
\begin{equation}
  I_{23} = \langle \{2, 3 \} \rangle = \{ 2 n + 3m : n, m \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
\end{equation}
That is the ideal consists of all the multiples of $2$ together with the multiples
of $3$, and their linear combinations. Then by choosing $n=0$ we get all multiples of $3$,
and by choosing $m=0$ we get all multiples of $2$. We could say that $2$ is the
smallest positive integer in the ideal $I_{23}$, but then that $3$ being in $I_{23}$ can
not be obtained from $2$ with an integer multiplication, so the proof above is wrong.
In fact that is not the case. We let you to prove that $I_{23}=\mathbb{Z}$,
and that in general $\langle \{ p, q \} \rangle$ is equal to
$\langle \{ o \} \rangle$, where $o=\text{gcd}(p,q)$. More generally,
for ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\langle \{ p_1, \cdots, p_k \} \rangle = \langle \{ o \} \rangle$ with
$o=\text{gcd}(p_1, \cdots, p_k)$.

The same argument used here can be applied to polynomials in one variable $\mathbb{K}[x]$, over the field $\mathbb{K}$. For polynomials in two or more variables the property breaks.

Comment: Explanation with an example is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, then, considering only the addition operator, $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ (ie $I$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, when viewed as a group under addition).  Since $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is cyclic, it follows that $(I,+)$ is cyclic (if you aren't convinced that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, you should sit down and prove it).

Therefore, $(I,+)$ **as a group** is generated by some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  So, for every $x\in I$, there exists $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$x=\underbrace{n+n+\cdots+n}_{m\textrm{ times}}$$ if $m>0$ or $$x=\underbrace{-n-n-\cdots-n}_{\vert m \vert \textrm{ times}}$$ if $m<0$ (and of course $x=0$ if $m=0$).  Thus, $I=\{nm\,\vert\,m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and now you only need show that,  **as an ideal**, $I$ is generated by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be the smallest integer in ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. 
Assume for contradiction $\exists a \in I$ so that $a$ is not divisible by $d$. Then we can represent $a$ as $a = qd + b$, for $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ 0 <b < d$. As $d$ is the smallest integer in $I$ and $d > b$, we know that $b \notin I$. As I is an ideal, we know that $qd \in I$. Therefore we have 
\begin{align}
a = qd + b \in I \\
qd \in I \\
b \notin I\\
\end{align}
Because I is an ideal, we know that $I$ is a group under addition, which implies $-qd \in I$, and $a - qd = b \in I$, which contradicts the assumption that $b \notin I$.