# Show every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ is of form $\langle p\rangle$ where $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

An ideal $P$ is called a prime ideal if whenever $ab\in P$ we have either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.  I am confused about how to connect the definition with with $\langle p\rangle$.

Comment: This fact is very useful: it is basically that "the maximal ideals are precisely the prime ideals in a principal ideal domain".

Comment: @user26857 Very true. I can't edit my comment now, but I should say "the nonzero prime ideals".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the [well-ordering principle](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Well-ordering_principle) to find a candidate $p$ to serve as the generator for your ideal. Then use the euclidean algorithm to show every element in the ideal must be a multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

> $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain.

This follows since it's a Euclidean domain; it has about a million answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101348/show-that-every-ideal-of-the-ring-mathbb-z-is-principal).

Therefore the ideals are precisely $\langle n \rangle$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\geq 0}$.

> The maximal ideals are precisely $\langle p \rangle$ for $p$ prime.

Proof: Since if $\langle pn \rangle$ is an ideal with $p$ prime and $n$ a non-zero nonunit integer, then $\langle p \rangle \supset \langle pn \rangle$; conversely, if $\langle p \rangle \subseteq \langle m \rangle$ then $m \mid p$ so $m=p$ or $m=1$.