# $\mathbb Z = A \sqcup B$ with conditions on the sums implies $A = \{\text{evens}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ named $X,Y$, we define $+$ operation as below:
$$X+Y = \{z \in \mathbb{Z}\mid z=x+y \:\text{ for some } x \in X, y \in Y\}.$$ Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}= A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $0 \in A$, and $B$ is a nonempty set. Also suppose that $A+A$, $A+B$ and $B+B$ are each equal to either $A$ or $B$. Can you get the conclusion that $A$ must be set of all even integers and $B$ must be the set of all odd integers?

Comment: When you define "+", did you mean to define it in the usual way (i.e. {z|z=x+y for x in X, y in Y}) or was that not a typo?

Comment: That "+" is the operation between two sets X + Y. I may use another simple to distinguish it from the usual one. Sorry.

Comment: @Lopsy, yayaya, you are right. Its z=x+y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Since $0\in A$, we have $A\subseteq A+A$ and $B\subseteq A+B$, so it follows that $A+A=A$ and $A+B=B$.  Let $x$ be an element of $A$.  If $-x$ were in $B$, then we would have $0=x+(-x)\in x+B\subseteq A+ B=B$ which contradicts $0\in A$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Thus $-x$ must be in $A$.

Since $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z$ that is closed under addition and additive inverses, $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.  Therefore $A=k\mathbb Z$ for some $k\geq0$. We can rule out $k=0$, because if $B=\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, then $B+B=\mathbb Z$.  We can rule out $k=1$, because $B$ is nonempty. Finally, we can rule out $k>2$, because if that were the case, $1+1$ would be in $B+B$ and in $B$, while $1-1$ would be in $B+B$ and in $A$, contradicting the hypothesis that $B+B$ is one of $A$ or $B$.

Therefore $A=2\mathbb Z$ is the set of even numbers, and $B=\mathbb Z\setminus 2\mathbb Z=1+(2\mathbb Z)$ is the set of odd numbers.

---

Here is an alternative to the approach in the second paragraph, not referring to groups.  Picking up from the first paragraph, so far we know that $A+A=A$, $A+B=B$, $-A=A$.  We can see similarly that $-B=B$ (if $x$ were in $B$ with $-x\in A$, we would have $0=x-x\in A+B=B$ again).  Since $B$ is nonempty, there exists $x\in B$, and therefore $0=x-x\in B+B$.  This implies that $B+B=A$.

If $1$ were in $A$, then using $A+A=A$ and induction we would have all positive integers in $A$, and using $-A=A$ we would have all the rest.  Since $B$ is nonempty, this is impossible, so $1$ is in $B$.  Thus $2=1+1\in B+B=A$.  Using $A+A=A$ and induction, all positive even integers are in $A$, and using $-A=A$ we get all the rest.  So $2\mathbb Z\subseteq A$.  Therefore $B=A+B\supseteq (2\mathbb Z)+1$, which is the set of odd numbers.  Since $A$ contains all even numbers and $B$ contains all odd numbers, we in fact have $A=2\mathbb Z$ and $B=1+(2\mathbb Z)$.

(Actually, this second approach seems somewhat similar to the approach in a now deleted answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have two questions for you. First, I don't get why -x must be in A. Second, I dont know the notation of a set \ a set.

Comment: For your first question, we know that if $-x\in B$, then $0=x+(-x)\in x+ B\subseteq A+B= B$, but this contradicts $0\in A$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  For your second question, $X\setminus Y$ is notation meaning $\{x\in X: x\not\in Y\}$, sometimes called the set-theoretic difference or relative complement of $Y$ in $X$.  E.g., $\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ is the set of nonzero integers.  In this problem we know $A=\mathbb Z\setminus B$ and $B=\mathbb Z\setminus A$.  A reference is the following article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement

Comment: @Shannon: I edited the first paragraph to clarify.

Comment: I am still confused. If B=Z\{0}, then B+B is a set without 0 in it. So it doesnt equal Z.

Comment: @Shannon: $1$ and $-1$ are both in $\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$, so $0=1+(-1)$ is in $(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})+(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})$.  For all $k\in\mathbb Z$, you can always find two nonzero integers whose sum is $k$, and therefore $(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})+(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. How do you know A=kZ? A could be just a random subset of Z.

Comment: @Shannon: There I used the fact that the only subgroups of the integers with addition are the cyclic subgroups.  I did not know whether this would be familiar to you, so I'm glad you asked.  It is a standard result usually covered in introductory courses in group theory that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.  There was a question about proving it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6998.  It is possible to show without using the group theoretic language, as it really only relies on division with remainder for integers.  ($\mathbb Z$ is generated as a group by $1$.)

Comment: Perfect. Group theory, that's what I am working on it. Appreciate for your help sooooo much.

Comment: @Shannon: You're welcome.  I added another approach that doesn't use that.