# Question about homomorphism of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

$G$ is cyclic group. $\varphi:G\to H$ is homomorphism.

How do I show that $\ker \varphi$ and $\text{Im}\varphi$ are cyclic groups?

Thank you!

Comment: $\ker(\varphi) < G$, so it is cyclic. $Im(\varphi) = \langle \varphi(a)\rangle$ where $a$ is a generator of $G$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\ker\varphi <G$? Thank you!

Comment: It means $\ker(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $G$. Do you know that a subgroup of a cyclic group must be cyclic?

Comment: I don't remember if we learn it, but it's look familiar.
It's hard to prove it?
BTW, there is another way to prove it?
Thank you!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan - can you write me a simple proof of it? thank you!

Comment: The proof will be there in pretty much any book on Group theory (for instance, look at Gallian/Herstein/Artin/etc)

Comment: You can check http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101121123720AAmzoBX

Comment: Concerning every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Say $G=\left< x\right>$. Let $H<G$. If $|H|=1$ then $H=\left< e\right>$. Let $|H|>1$. Let $n$ be the least positive integer such that $x^n \in H$. Let $y \in H$ so $y=x^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the division algorithm, there exists unique $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m=nq+r$ and $0\leq r<n$. Hence, $y=x^m=x^{nq+r}=x^{nq}x^r$ and so $x^m*x^{-nq}=x^r$ but $x^m,x^{-nq} \in H$ so $x^r\in H$ but $n$ is the least positive integer such that $x^n \in H$, so as $r<n$, it must be $r=0$ so $y=x^{nq}\in H$ so $H=\left<x^n\right>$.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the book for solving the second statement of your problem [(see Theorem $13.9$)](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=23PmtnVdZWcC&pg=PA513&lpg=PA513&dq=homomorphic+image+of+a+cyclic+group+is+cyclic&source=bl&ots=wUay5-eT0q&sig=zPZ_L7B-624kKt1P9UuC9ddkldg&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=rsKxUrb4Jqe4iAedsoCwAw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=homomorphic%20image%20of%20a%20cyclic%20group%20is%20cyclic&f=false).

By Theorem $13.3$ of the book on that link, ker$\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (In fact we only need ker$\phi$ is a subgroup of $G$) . Since $G$ is cyclic, and by the fact that subgroup of cyclic group is [cyclic](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic), we are done the first statement.

Comment: Every subgroup of a cyclic group is normal...

Comment: @user1729: I edited my answer

Comment: @user1729: You can check the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof

Comment: I understand the proof, I just don't understand your point(s). The fact that the kernel is normal is irrelevant - are you just saying that it is a subgroup? I also don't understand why you linked to a book, in the sense that this question isn't overly difficult so a standard answer or hint would be better...

Comment: It would be more self contained to give more information about what is said in Theorem 13.9. Links can go stale, and that would render this answer less useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\ker(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $G$, so it is cyclic. Moreover, $\operatorname{im}(\phi)=\langle \phi(a)\rangle$ where $a$ is a generator of $G$.

(I have made this a community wiki answer, as it is simply Prahlad Vaidyanathan's comment. Answering this question removes it from the unanswered queue, and I dislike the other answer because it basically points at a book.)