# Any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to do **Exercise 2.2.4** from textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell.

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group. Then any subgroup $H$ of $G$ is cyclic.

Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains errors? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

Assume $G = \{g^n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$ and $H = \{\ldots,g^{-n_2}, g^{-n_1}, g^0, g^{n_1}, g^{n_2}, \ldots\}$ where $0 <n_1<n_2<\cdots<\infty$. We have $n_p$ is divisible by $n_1$. If not, $n_p = q n_1 + r$ where $0 < r < n_1$. Then $g^{r} = g^{n_p - qn_1} = g^{n_p} (g^{-n_1})^q \in H$, which is a contradiction. As such $H$ is generated by $g^{n_1}$.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Many thanks for your verification @freakish :))

Comment: Compare alos with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @freakish's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list.

> Looks ok to me.