# About a case in a proof that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

In the following proof I do not understand why it is assumed that $\{e\}$ is cyclic and why we treat the case $h = \{e\}$ separately.

Let $G$ be a cyclic group generated by $a.$

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

If $H=\{e\},$ then $H$ is a cyclic group subgroup generated by $e$.

Let $H\neq\{e\}.$

By definition of cyclic group, every element of $G$ has the form $an$.

Then as $H$ is a subgroup of $G, an\in H$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Let $m$ be the smallest (strictly) positive integer such that $am\in H.$

Consider an arbitrary element $b$ of $H$.

As $H$ is a subgroup of $G, b=an$ for some $n$.

By the Division Theorem, it is possible to find integers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=mq+r$ with $0\le r<m.$

It follows that:

$$an=amq+r=(am)qar$$
and hence:

$$ar=(am)−qan$$

Since $am\in H$ so is its inverse $(am)^{−1}.$

By Group Axiom G0: Closure, so are all powers of its inverse.

Now $an$ and $(am)−q$ are both in $H$, thus so is their product $ar,$ again by Group Axiom G0: Closure.

However:

$m$ was the smallest (strictly) positive integer such that $am\in H$
and:

$$0\le r<m$$
Therefore it follows that:

$$r=0$$
Therefore:

$$n=qm$
and:

$$b=an=(am)q.$$
We conclude that any arbitrary element $b=an$ of $H$ is a power of $am$.

So, by definition, $H=\langle am\rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense.  Are you to prove that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic?

Comment: Duplicate: [A subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof?rq=1).

Comment: @amWhy Not a dupe of that since the question is whether or not it is necessary to separate out the case of the trivial subgroup (i.e. can the general proof work in this case?), which is not answered there.

Comment: MathJax basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic - Understanding Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof)

Comment: @Shaun Not a dupe of that either, see my prior comment.

Comment: Fair enough, @BillDubuque; I will retract my vote to close. Thank you.

Comment: I've done my best to format the maths. Have I done it right, @NikylMason?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to consider $\{e\}$ separately (as far as I am aware): the subgroups of $G=\langle a\rangle$ correspond to multiples (or "powers") of $a$, and we say, by convention, that $a^0=e$, the zero-th power of $a$; perhaps the additive nature of abelian groups (and hence cyclic groups) calls to question how one defines $0a$, which is the additive way of taking the zero-th power - the zero-th multiple of $a$ (which is still $e$ by convention) - and so, here, for pedagogical reasons, it is put to one side conceptually; and, besides, if $G$ is infinite, $\{e\}$ is its only finite subgroup.