# Subgroups for $F=(\mathbb Z_{12},+)$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups

I'm working with the following.

1. Find all subgroups for $F=(\mathbb Z_{12},+)$
2. Which subgroups are cyclic groups?

$1,5,7,11$ generate $F$.
$$\left \langle [2] \right \rangle = \left \{[0], [2], [4], [6], [8], [10]   \right \}\\
\left \langle [3] \right \rangle = \left \{[0], [3], [6], [9]   \right \}\\
etc.$$

How do I know which are cyclic groups?

Bonus questions:

3. If it would be subgroups for $F=(Z_{12},\cdot)$, would the subgroups be...?
   $$\left \langle [2] \right \rangle = \left \{[0], [2], [4], [8]   \right \}\\
   \left \langle [3] \right \rangle = \left \{[0], [3], [9]   \right \}$$

Comment: [a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof); and $[0]$ is not an element of $(\mathbb Z_{12},\cdot)$

Comment: All subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic. Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295564/104041

Comment: To start with, look for the subsets of $F$ closed under addition modulo $12$.