# Clarification on proof that subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

For the proof that a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, I've seen the use of the Division Theorem to prove that if the group $G$ is generated by $a$, then $a^m$ generates a subgroup $H$, where $m$ is the least positive integer such that $a^m\in H$.

However, I'm confused as to why we use $a^m$. Isn't any subgroup also just generated by $a$?

Sorry if this question seems dumb, I'm pretty new to group theory and proof writing.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295564/a-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic-understanding-proof) answer your question?

Comment: When we say a subgroup $H$ is generated by $a$, $a$ must be a member of $H$. The infinite cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$, but its subgroup $\{2i \mid i \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is generated by $2$ (or $-2$) and not by $1$.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: On the same note, given any element of a group, there is exactly one subgroup that it generates.