# Proof that all subgroups of $(\Bbb Z_{15},+)$ are cyclic and list all of its distinct groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Two questions:

1. Prove that all subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{15}$ are cyclic
2. List all distinct groups of $\Bbb Z_{15}$.

For part 1) I've done this much:

$$\gcd(r,15) = 1$$

The generators are $1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14$

I'm not sure what to do from this point.

Thanks

Comment: For (1), the subgroups have order either 1, 3, 5, 15 by Lagrange. Each is cyclic.

Comment: To make your life simple for the first part: Show that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: Can you use the homomorphism theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Any subgroup of any cyclic group is itself cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295564/104041)

By Lagrange's theorem, the subgroups have orders $1,3,5$ or $15$. It is then easy to see that the subgroups are $$\{[0]_{15}\},$$ $$\{[0]_{15}, [5]_{15}, [10]_{15}\},$$ $$\{[0]_{15}, [3]_{15}, [6]_{15}, [9]_{15}, [12]_{15}\},$$ and $\Bbb Z_{15}$, where

$$[a]_{n}=\{b\in\Bbb Z : n\mid a-b\}.$$