# About every subgroup of $ ( \mathbb{Z} , + ) $ being cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm citing below the definition of and a theorem about cyclic groups, as it is written in my book (Algebra, by Thomas Hungerford):

> **Definition:**
>
> Let $ G $ be a group **(notation is multiplicative in here.)** For every $ a \in G, $ a cyclic group is: $ \langle a \rangle = \{a^n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\} $

and,

> **Theorem:**
>
> Every subgroup $ H $ of the additive group $ ( \mathbb{Z},+ ) $ is cyclic. Either $ H = \langle 0 \rangle, $ or $ H = \langle m \rangle, $ where $ m $ is the least positive integer in $ H $.

---

My question is;

I know that, and I would, express $ H $ as the union of all $ H_m = \{ m \mathbb{Z} : m \in H \} $.

The reason why I'm specifying this notation is that I don't understand the fact that $ m $ should be the **least** integer there (if I get it right of course.)

Thank you for giving advice.

Comment: Hint: consider the common divisors of elements of $H$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use division with remainder to show that $H = m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m$. For let $m$ be the smallest positive element of $H$. (If $H=\{0\}$, there is nothing to prove.) Then for any $k \in H$, we have

$$ k = q \cdot m + r \qquad \text{for some }q\text{, with } 0 \leq r < m.$$
Since both $k$ and $m$ lie in $H$ and $H$ is a subgroup, this means $r \in H$. But $m$ was the smallest positive element, so $r = 0$.

Comment: Thank you SvanN... I was concretely confused. But indeed, this way, it helps.

Answer (score 2):

$ H$ closed under subtraction $\Rightarrow$ $H$ closed under remainder $= \bmod $ (via repeated subtraction) hence $H$ is closed under $\gcd,\,$ since gcds are computable by repeated $\!\bmod$ (or subtraction) by Euclid. Now it's easy to show $H$ is generated by the gcd of its elements - its least positive element (for $H\neq 0)$

This is the intuition behind the proof. You might find it enlightening to see how it is employed in [this proof of Bezout's GCD identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242).  These ideas will be clarified when one  studies (principal) ideals in rings, and the result that Euclidean domains are PIDs (a generalization of Bezout)

Comment: Thank you Bill.
To specify, my trouble wasn't about the method, but the idea behind.

Comment: @bugrahaskan The idea is as I explained, i.e. being closed under (repeated) subtraction implies $H$ is closed under gcds, so $H$ is generated by the gcd of all its elements, necessarily the least positive element. Algorithmically it amounts to applying the Euclidean algorithm to compute $\,\gcd(h_1,h_2,h_3,\ldots)\ $

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719321/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4318053/242) for further conceptual elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H\neq \{0\}=\langle 0\rangle$. Then $\exists h\in H$ such that $h\neq 0$. Let $$m=\min \{g\in H\mid 0\lt g\leq |h|\}$$ where $|h|=h$ if $h\gt 0$, and $|h|=-h$ if $h\lt 0$. Note $m$ exists by well-ordering principle. We claim $H= \langle m\rangle=\{km\mid k\in \Bbb{Z}\}$. Since $m\in H$ and $H$ is closed under $+$, we have $km\in H$ for all $k\in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus $\langle m\rangle\subseteq H$. Assume towards contradiction, $\exists a\in H$ such that $a\notin \langle m\rangle$. That is $m \nmid a$. By division algorithm, $a=mq+r$ where $q\in \Bbb{Z}$ and $0\lt r\lt |m|=m$. Since $-mq=m(-q)\in \langle m\rangle$, we have $-mq\in H$. So $a-mq=r\in H$. So $\exists r\in H$ such that $0\lt r\lt m$. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $H\subseteq \langle m\rangle$ and $H= \langle m\rangle$.