# Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$, let $a \in G$ have order $n$. Let $m$ be an integer then prove that $a^m =e$ iff $n$ divides $m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I have encountered this question in a book. I have no clue how to approach the question. How should I go about it? I was thinking of maybe writing m in terms of n, since we have `m ≡ 0(mod n)`.

I tried to contradict it by taking some n which does not divide m. I am not sure if that is the correct procedure

Comment: If $n$ divides $m$, then $m=nk $, so $am=ank=ek=e$

Comment: How is e^k = e, given e can be any element of the group and not essentially 1, and k can be any integer.

Comment: Your title says $e$ is the identity element; by the way, you should put the question in the body, and the title should be a description of what the question is about

Comment: Could you show $n$ is not the order of $a$ if $am=e$ and $n\nmid m$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. e is the identity but identity of a group with some operation can be anything. Since the operation has not been mentioned, how can we say e^k = e?

Comment: if $e$ is the identity element then always $ek=e$; you could prove that by induction using the facts that $e=e$ (base case) and $e$ is inert

Comment: Do you mean $\, m\cdot a = e\ $ or $\, a^m = e,\ $ i.e. are you using additive or multiplicative notation?

Comment: a^m = e. m is the power of a.

Comment: Ok, you wrotye it additively in the title. I will change that and my answer.

Comment: I tried to contradict it by taking some n which does not divide m. I am not sure if that is the correct procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\impliedby:\;$  If $n|m,$ then $m=nk,$ so $a^m=a^{(nk)}={(a^n)}^k=e^k=e$.

$\implies:\;$  If $a^m=e$ and $n\nmid m$, then $0<\gcd(n,m)<n$ but $a^{\gcd(n,m)}=e,$ (*)

contradicting the assumption that $a$ has order $n$.

---

Addendum (from my comments, as suggested by [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque))

to justify the inequalities and equality on the line marked (*) above:

$0<\gcd(n,m)<n,$ because $n\ne0$ so $0<\gcd(n,m),$ and if $\gcd(n,m)=n$ then we'd have $n|m$.

By [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), $\gcd(n,m)=nx+my$, so $a^{\gcd(n,m)}=a^{nx+my}=(a^n)^x(a^m)^y=e^xe^y=e$.

Comment: At this level one should justify the two claimed (in)equalities after "then" in direction $\Longrightarrow$. We could also use $\, m\bmod n\,$ vs. $\gcd(m,n)\,$ to achieve the descent there (which is a special case of the proof that subgroups / ideal of $\Bbb Z$ are cyclic / principal, via the Euclidean algorithm, either in slow (subtractive) form or faster mod / gcd form).

Comment: justification:  $n\ne0$ so $0<\gcd(n,m)$, and if $\gcd(n,m)=n$ then we'd have $n|m$

Comment: The *in*equality is the easy part. You still need to justify the equality $\,a^{\gcd(n,m)} = e,\,$ which is usually the most difficult part for students (not only proving it, but understanding how to *discover* such a proof - which is clarified when one proceeds more conceptually as in my answer).

Comment: by Bezout, $\gcd(n,m)=nx+my$ so $a^{\gcd(n,m)}=a^{nx+my}=(a^n)^x(a^m)^y=e^xe^y=e$

Comment: That's one way. Ideally the proofs should be in the answer (or linked) not in comments, since comments are ephemeral, not searched, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ H := \{m\in\Bbb Z\ :\ a^m = 1\}\,$ is *closed under subtraction*, so is a *subgroup* $\,\{0\}\subsetneq H\subseteq \Bbb Z.\,$ [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048795/242) $\,H = n\Bbb Z\,$ where $\,n = $ least element $>0\,$  of $\,H.\,$ So $\,a^m = 1\!\iff\! m\in n\Bbb Z\!\iff\! n\mid m$

**Remark** $ $ Though it is easy to verify the set forms a subgroup by said *subgroup test*, it is more *conceptual* to do so by viewing $H$ as the kernel of the group hom: $\, m\mapsto a^m\,$ from $\,\Bbb Z\to G,\,$ presuming that viewpoint is already known.

Comment: I write $1\,$ vs. $\,e\,$ as the neutral element.