# Exercise 10, Section 1.3 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, group-isomorphism

> An infinite group is cyclic if and only if it is isomorphic to each of its proper subgroups.

**My attempt:** Let $G$ be an infinite group. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $G=\langle a\rangle$. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$, i.e. $H\neq \{e\}, G$. By theorem 5 section 1.3, $H=\langle a^m\rangle$ where $m$ is least positive integer such that $a^m\in H$. Since $G$ is infinite, we have $a^i\neq a^j$, if $ i\neq j$. So $H$ is infinite. By [theorem 2 section 1.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4667504/861687), $G\cong \Bbb{Z}$ and $H\cong \Bbb{Z}$. Since $\cong$ is an equivalence relation, we have $G\cong H$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $G\cong H$, for all $\{e\}\neq H\lt G$. Let $a\in G\setminus \{e\}$. By hypothesis, $G\cong \langle a\rangle$. That is $\exists f:\langle a\rangle \to G$ such that $f$ is homomorphism and bijective. By theorem 5 section 1.3, $\text{Im} f=\langle f(a)\rangle =G$. Thus $G$ is cyclic. **Is my proof correct?**

---

**Edit:** Thanks to User Greg Martin for commenting, possibility of $\langle a\rangle$ not being a proper subgroup. If $\langle a\rangle$ is not a proper subgroup, then $\langle a\rangle =\{e\}$ or $\langle a\rangle =G$. Since $e\neq a\in \langle a\rangle$, we have $\langle a\rangle \neq \{e\}$. So $\langle a\rangle =G$. Thus $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. Maybe, you should just add a sentence to explain why $\langle a \rangle$ can't be finite as you haven't used explicitly the hypothesis that $G$ is infinite.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you mean in $(\Leftarrow )$ part of proof, if yes, then I think we don’t care about cardinality of $\langle a\rangle$. We used $G$ is infinite assumption in showing existence of $a$ (non identity element of $G$).

Comment: The second half is basically a correct proof of the statement "If a group with more than one element is isomorphic to each of its proper subgroups, then it is cyclic". (We don't know whether $\langle a\rangle$ is a proper subgroup or not, but if it's not then it's trivially isomorphic to $G$.) It doesn't use the infinite assumption, and indeed cyclic groups of prime order also have this property since there are no proper subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct part is correct. For the reverse part of the equivalence, I would say the following.

Let $a \in G \setminus \{e\}$. If $G = \langle a\rangle$, we are done. Otherwise $\langle a \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and isomorphic to $G$ by hypothesis. $\langle a \rangle$ is infinite, as $G$  is supposed to be infinite. According to theorem 2, section 1.3, $\langle a \rangle$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Z$ and therefore $G$ too. We therefore get the desired conclusion that $G$ is cyclic infinite.

Comment: @user264745 $\langle a \rangle$ is finite or countable cyclic by definition.

Comment: Yaa. My bad. Thank you for the answer.