# If $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^k=1$ and $a^n=1$, where $a$ is an element of group $G$, $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then $k$ divides $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am hoping for verification of this proof. My concern is if the contradiction really refutes that k does not divide n.

**PROOF**

Let $a\in G$ where $G$ is a group.  Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $a^k=1$.  Let $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, such that $a^n=1$.

This implies that $k\le n$.  If $k=n$ and $p=1$, then $n=kp$.  Thus $k$ divides $n$.

Now consider $k<n$.

If $k=1$, then $a^k=a^1=1$.  Choose $m=n$.  Then $n=m=1m=km$ and $k$ divides $n$.

Now assume $k>1$ and assume $\forall q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\ne kq$.
Since  $1<k<n$ we can exclude the cases on $q\le 0$ and we consider only $q>0$.

Choose a $q$ such that $kq<n$ and $k(q+1)>n$.  This $q$ exists in view of the division algorithm, $n=kq+r$, where $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le r < \vert k\vert = k$.  This implies that $kq=n-r<n$ and $n< kq+k = k(q+1)$.

Subtracting $kq$ from both sides of the latter inequality gives $0<n-kq<k$.

Thus, we have $a^n=1=1^q=(a^k)^q=a^{kq}$.  This implies that $a^{n-qk}=1$.  Since $n-kq<k$, this implies that k is not the smallest positive integer such that $a^k=1$, a contradiction.

Hence, there exists a $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=kq$.  Therefore $k$ divides $n$.

Comment: Can't you just write $n=kq + r$ where $0\leq r<k$ and then $a^n = (a^k)^q*a^r = a^r = 1$ and since $r < k$, $r=0$?

Comment: If you know about subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, then the set $\{ n \in \mathbb Z : a^n =1\}$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and so is generated by its smallest positive element.

Comment: @Snowball yes. But I should have had $0<r<k$. Thank you.

Comment: @Ihf not that far along yet. Just started with group theory. Thank you, though.

Comment: The proofs in the linked dupes (by Euclidean descent) also work here. You are on the way to rediscover them (in less concise form).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque thank you. That is excellent. I actually wanted to prove this statement for a problem that asked whether or not it $k$ divides $n$, but did not ask for the proof. Basically, in chapter 1.1 of the abstract algebra book I just started. I am just happy I was on the right track, which it seems was so, despite an unoptimized proof. Your link, however, is very informative.

Comment: Glad it helped. I expanded [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719321/242)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque so cool. I am just learning real mathematics myself (I am a chemist and pharmacist). Such examples are why I find it so amazing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the proof.  If $k \nmid n$, then by the division algorithm $\exists q, r \in \Bbb Z^+~(n=kq+r)$, where $0 \lt r \lt k$.  But then $1=a^n= a^{kq} a^r=({a^k})^q a^r=1^qa^r=a^r $, contradicting the minimality of $k$.

Comment: Thank you. And, in turn, showing that contradiction provides for divisibility, as non-divisibility was implied in the $r>0$.